# JAVA: POST data via HTTPS does not seem to get sent?

Tags: java, post, https

I have a problem POSTing data via HTTPS in Java. The server response is the same whether or not I send 'query'. Maybe someone can point out what the problem is...

Thanks!

Main class:

```
package bind;

public class Main {

    public static final String urlString = "https://www.sms.ethz.ch/cgi-bin/sms/send.pl";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

 Message msg = new Message("Alles klar?");
 URL url = new URL(urlString);

 String[][] values = new String[3][2];
 values[0][0] = "action";
 values[0][1] = "listoriginators";
 values[1][0] = "username";
 values[1][1] = "xxxxxx";
 values[2][0] = "password";
 values[2][1] = "xxxxxx";


 Query query = new Query(values);
 System.out.println("Query: " + query.getQuery());

 Request request = new Request(url.getURL(), query.getQuery());


    }
}
```

Request class:

```
package bind;

public class Request {
    static private int ic = 0;
    private URL url;

    protected Request(java.net.URL URL, String query){
 ic++;
 if(CONSTANTS.SHOW_LOGS) { System.out.println("log: new instance of 'Message'"); }

 // connect
 try {

     System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
     java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

     javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection connection = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) URL.openConnection();
     connection.setDoInput(true);
     connection.setDoOutput(true);
     connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     connection.setFollowRedirects(true);

     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www- form-urlencoded");
     connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");

     java.io.DataOutputStream output = new java.io.DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

     output.writeBytes(query); // <<-- NOTHING CHANGES IF I COMMENT THIS OUT OR NOT !!??!?!

     System.out.println("log: response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
     System.out.println("log: response message: " + connection.getResponseMessage());

     java.io.DataInputStream input = new java.io.DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
     for(int i = input.read(); i != -1; i = input.read()) {
  System.out.print((char)i);
     }
     System.out.print("\n");
     input.close();

 } catch(java.io.IOException e) {
     if(CONSTANTS.SHOW_LOGS) {
  System.out.println("error: unable to connect");
  System.out.println(e);
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

    }
}
```

URL Class:

```
public class URL {
    static private int ic = 0;
    private String URLString;
    private java.net.URL url;

    protected URL(String a_url){
 ic++;

 if(CONSTANTS.SHOW_LOGS) { System.out.println("log: new instance of 'URL'"); }

 setURLString(a_url);
 createURL();
    }

    private void setURLString(String a_url) {
 URLString = a_url;
    }

    private void createURL() {
 try {
     url = new java.net.URL(URLString);
 } catch(java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
     System.out.println("error: invalid URL");
     System.out.println(e);
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
    }

    private void showURL() {
 System.out.println("URL: " + url.getHost() + url.getPath());
    }

    public java.net.URL getURL() {
 return url;
    }

}
```

PS: mostly from here: http://www.java-samples.com/java/POST-toHTTPS-url-free-java-sample-program.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urk. Could you possibly be persuaded to use the [Apache commons http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) instead?

[This link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) is more direct.

It's a lot less work than debugging this code.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for the tip about Apache commons libs, they are amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `flush()` or, better, `close()` the stream afterwards (which already does an implicit flush). Flushing is necessary because the data may be internally buffered to a certain length and flushing forces the entire buffer to be actually written to the output.

So, change

```
 output.writeBytes(query);
```

to

```
 output.writeBytes(query);
 output.close();
```

Actually, the normal idiom is to close streams in the `finally` block of the `try` block as you've acquired them, so that you can guarantee that they get closed whenever an `IOException` occurs during the write. Closing is important because it frees up system resources.

```
Stream stream = null; // Can be InputStream, OutputStream, Reader or Writer.
try {
    stream = new SomeStream();
    // ...
} finally {
    if (stream != null) try { stream.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {} // You can if necessary bake an utility method taking Closeable or take a look for commons IO.
}
```

Also see the [Sun Java IO tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) for more basic lessons and guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this doesn't change anything though. I had actually tried that before (don't know why I removed it again). I might try the Apache Commons HTTP Client bmargulies mentioned above.

Comment: You did call `output.close()` **before** calling `connection.getInputStream()`, did you?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have been using the Apache libs mentioned by bmargulies so I sort of dropped this issue. But I did add  it on the line right after output.writeBytes(query), still didn't work.

I think it may just have something to do with ssl... Anyway I have moved to the Apache libs and they work great.

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark his answer as accepted, else this question will remain unanswered.